# MailKit SearchQuery.FromContains("")

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am writing a spam deletion tool for myself. I want this filter to include email where the "FROM" field is empty. Unfortunately, when I try to enter such a definition by searching for an empty string like this...

```
SearchQuery.FromContains("")
```

... I get an error saying that the string cannot be empty.

Anybody have any ideas on this? How can I filter emails based on an empty "TO" or "FROM" field?

Comment: If the answer Jeffrey provided works for you, you probably want to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the grey checkmark next to it. (You might also give it an upvote while you're at it.) Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

The IMAP SEARCH command is the wrong approach for this, unfortunately, because a search for an empty string will match everything (not just messages with an empty From header or an empty From address).

The best way to do this would be something more like this:

```
var messages = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);
var spamUids = new UniqueIdSet ();
foreach (var message in messages) {
    if (message.Envelope?.From.Count == 0) {
        // This means there are 0 addresses in the From header
        spamUids.Add (message.UniqueId);
        continue;
    }

    if (message.Envelope?.To.Count == 0) {
        // This means there are 0 addresses in the To header
        spamUids.Add (message.UniqueId);
        continue;
    }
}
```